Dynamically create a class with generic parameters using System.Reflection.Emit
I've been searching for ways to dynamically create a class with generic parameters using System.Reflection.Emit.
I would like that class type to have a type.FullName equal to this:
type.FullName = "Blazor.Tools.BlazorBundler.Interfaces.IViewModel2[[Blazor.Tools.BlazorBundler.Entities.SampleObjects.Models.Employee, Blazor.Tools.BlazorBundler.Entities.SampleObjects.Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[Blazor.Tools.BlazorBundler.Interfaces.IModelExtendedProperties, Blazor.Tools.BlazorBundler.Interfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]"

I was able to create the class but not with the expected type FullName property. It somehow tries to trim it to the base type name. I hope there is someone who knows how to do this. I'll accept it as an answer if it can include the generic parameters in it's FullName property even if it is not the exact type name.
To illustrate this in a sample code, here are the links:
[.NetFiddle]
https://dotnetfiddle.net/SsZFyo
[Replit]
https://replit.com/join/mgufadlhrk-solomiosisante
[Paiza.io]
https://paiza.io/projects/siVkQFl0ktvcX6VVtDnCZA
